# Can I create such chart with highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a simple bar graph and I wanted to add percentage change over the top of those bars.

Check the inline image.

[image: Revenue & Percentage Change]

I read the highcharts documentation and I did not see anything similar. So can we create such chart with highcharts with some hacks, if yes I would appreciate a code sample since my javascript skills are rudimentary. If not then can you suggest some alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With code all things are possible :)

Here's an example which uses a secondary value as the data label:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'  
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function(){
                    return this.series.userOptions.someValues[this.point.x] + '%';   
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        someValues: [10, 22, 35, 16, 61, 34, 13, 73, 43, 51, 12, 37],
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
```

Produces (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DX68q/)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark, you are a god among men, this exactly what I want. There is a tiny problem though. Is there anyway we can disable(or not show) percentage value for the first column.

Comment: I was able to figure out how to not show the value for the first column. Mark I have accepted your answer. Thanks once again.